# What's the difference between jaxws-ri and jaxws-rt?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

See the JAX-WS Maven repository from *java.net* - http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/xml/ws/

There are two similar folders - **jaxws-rt** and **jaxws-ri**. Currently, I'm using the **jaxws-rt** and it's working fine.

Here are my questions:

1. What's the difference between ***ri*** and ***rt***?
2. Does ***ri*** stand for *reference implementation* and ***rt*** stand for *runtime*?

Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As an answer to your **second question**:  Yes, you are right.

Below is the proof.

---

**RI** stands for *Reference Implementation*.

Quote from the official [**JAX-WS project home page**](http://jax-ws.java.net/) (an old site, see the UPDATE section below):

> Welcome to the JAX-WS **Reference Implementation** (**RI**) Project.

Plus in the [**POM file for the *jaxws-ri***](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-ri/2.2.8-promoted-b146/pom) (version 2.2.8 at the time of writing) we can find the following:

```
<name>JAX-WS RI Standalone Zipped Bundle</name>
<description>Open source Reference Implementation of JSR-224: Java API for XML Web Services Distribution Bundle</description>
```

---

**RT** stands for *Runtime*.

In the [**POM file for the *jaxws-rt***](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.8-promoted-b146/pom) (version 2.2.8 at the time of writing) we can find the following:

```
<name>JAX-WS RI Runtime Bundle</name>
```

(The word *Runtime* gives us a hint :-))

---

### UPDATE (April 2019)

The were quite a few changes in the Java EE world recently. Java EE was moved to *Eclipse Enterprise for Java* (**EE4J**). Read [EE4J FAQ](https://www.eclipse.org/ee4j/faq.php) for more information.

And JAX-WS project, which is now part of the EE4J, has also moved to another place:

- JAX-WS project's home page: https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/
- JAX-WS project's code is hosted on GitHub:
  https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/metro-jax-ws

Answer (score 12):

Looks like `-ri` generates the zip file for distribution (e.g. for use on the java.net web site), whereas `-rt` is for use as a Maven dependency. So you should keep using it.

**EDIT**: The other answer is more accurate and should be accepted

Comment: Does ri mean reference implementation? what about rt?

Comment: Actually, @artbristol's answer isn't so bad - it helped me realize that the -rt package is the one I want (since the -ri package is only available as a .pom/.zip file, not a plain .jar)