# migration from jdk 8 to jdk 11 cxf generated sources unknown imports

Tags: java, migration, cxf

I'm migrating from java 8 to 11 and I'm having a problem launching the springboot server:

> nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax / jws / WebService.

I used in my pom.xml:

```
maven-compiler 3.8.0
cxf.version 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT
```

the compilation goes well but not the start of the server
thank you

Answer (score 7):

JAX-WS is the library that provides `javax.jws.WebService` and related classes. It was supplied as part of Java SE 8 through 10, but removed for Java 11. You will need to get that library as an external dependency.

If you are using maven, you should be able to add a dependency on `com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:<current-version>` in your pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: thank you , I Have another problème now : Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]

Comment: my jaxb & jaxws dependencies are :
javax.xml.bind:jaxbapi:2.3.1
org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1
com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core2.3.1
com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1
com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.0
javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.1

Comment: The original version of your Dependency might be incomplete.  I had to add `<type>pom</type>` because it isn't a jar in the repository.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think so. That `<type>pom</type>` seems to be more for the `<dependencyManagement>` section (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778276/what-is-the-difference-between-pom-type-dependency-with-scope-import-and-wit). And I've got a HelloWorld example running with this dependency specification as is. Typically, Maven dependencies don't require specifying a `<type>`.

Comment: You can also use jaxws-rt instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401358/whats-the-difference-between-jaxws-ri-and-jaxws-rt then you don't need the type:pom.

Answer (score 3):

If Andrew's answer doesn't work, this fixed it for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

That's the **runtime** dependency instead of reference implementation - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401358/whats-the-difference-between-jaxws-ri-and-jaxws-rt) for more info