# Java 11: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebService

Tags: java, maven, cxf, java-11

First of all, I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727322/migration-from-jdk-8-to-jdk-11-cxf-generated-sources-unknown-imports) but there are not so many information - pom.xml is missing, so the root cause could be different.

In pom.xml I have:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-metrics</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Versions which are missing here are defined in parent pom.

Error which I get is:

```
TOMCAT 2021-08-01 19:03:37,603 [main] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/provisioning/webservice/lbx]- Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jws/WebService
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpointUtils.hasWebServiceAnnotation(CxfEndpointUtils.java:84) ~[camel-cxf-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jws.WebService
```

I also tried with `<artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>` and

```
<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
```

but without success.

Comment: Have you tried using <exclude>javaxb-api</exclude> from camel-cxf dependency?

Comment: You mean exclude <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId><artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>? I haven't, let me try.


@Edit unfortunatelly, it didn't help - I excluded `<groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>                  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>` from `camel-cxf` but still see the same error ;/

Answer (score 1):

Adding these dependencies fixed the issue for me:

```
implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '4.0.0', ext: 'pom'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '4.0.1'
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0359'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '4.0.1'
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.main.javaee-api', name: 'javax.jws', version: '3.1.2.2'
```